# What are the ways one may solve $2x+e^x=0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What are the ways one may solve $2x+e^x=0$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: You can prove that there exists a solution, but finding it explicitly via some algebraic expression is not possible. You need to use approximation methods such as bisection, fixed-point, Newton's and others

Comment: plot the respective curves and count the intersection points

Comment: I see. Thank you boon, best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  only analytical solution is given using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which leads $$x=-W\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\approx -0.351734$$

The remaining solution involve numerical methods, such as Newton. Considering $$f(x)=2x+e^x\implies f'(x)=2+e^x$$ the fist derivative being always positive, there is only one solution. If you start using, as a guess, $x_0=0$, you will obtain the following iterates
$$x_1=-0.33333333333333333333$$ $$x_2=-0.35168933155541534177$$ $$x_3=-0.35173371099294263019$$ $$x_4=-0.35173371   124919582602$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: I was hoping to solve it without numerical methods, but thank you a lot for both solutions!

Comment: @bru1987. This is the only analytical solution. In fact, remember that any equation which can write $A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$ has solution(s) in terms of Lambert function.

Comment: It should be noted that what Claude has shown here is the solution corresponding to the principal branch of the Lambert function, $W(z)=W_0(z)$; the other possible solutions are now complex.

Comment: As the root isn't far from the origin, a reasonable starting value is obtained by Taylor limited to quadratic terms: $2x+1+x+x^2/2=0$ yields $\sqrt7-3\approx-0.354248$

Answer (score 2):

The [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications) can be used to solve such equations:
$$x=-W(1/2)$$

Comment: I'll look into that, it seems thats exactly the solution I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Fixed point iteration.

$x = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}e^{\cdots}}}$

Comment: What method did tou use there MrYouMath?

Comment: @bru1987 Google "Fixed Point Iteration". It says that if $f(x) = x$ has a solution and $f$ satisfies certain conditions (that it is a "contraction mapping" at the solution, you can Google that as well), that the sequence $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ converges to that solution.

Comment: GFauxPas I see. Is Newton's method a special case of Fixed Point Iteration? I see how I could use that to solve it...

Comment: @mryoumath Isn't the function $\frac{-1}2 e^x$ though?

Comment: @GFauxPas: Thank you!

Comment: I see GFauxPas, thank you so much.

Comment: @bru1987 I was wrong, you can use FPI to solve $x - \frac {f(x)}{f'(x)} = x$ in Newton's method.

Comment: I see FauxPas thank you for clarifying. I have a question for you @GFauxPas and You Math : why was my question rated -1 immediately when I posted it? Is it too simplistic? Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Comment: I did not downvote. But as this is not your first post you should know that users of MSE want to see some of your efforts or thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Ok I see, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Graphically. For instance
$$
\frac{e^x}{x}=-2
$$
and plot the function $x \mapsto \frac{e^x}{x}$. The point $x=0$ is harmless, since it is not a solution of yout equation.

Comment: By using a graphing device that would definitely be possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the equation as $e^x=-2x$, then sketch the graphs of the exponential curve $y=e^x$ and the negatively sloped line $y=-2x$, you can see there is a single point of intersection in the interval $-1\lt x\lt0$. (Actually it should be easy to see that the intersection occurs in the interval $-1/2\lt x\lt0$.)  As other answers have noted, the solution can be expressed analytically with the Lambert function, but otherwise can only be approximated numerically.